# How to know if in before download image (Real, RC or Daily) Has already version inside of package? KDE 5.19 does have current daily?

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04

How to know if in before download image (Real, RC or Daily) Has already version inside of package? KDE 5.19 does have current daily?

How to look for package list of versions or exact version when was included?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 isn't on-topic here yet as it's still a development release. Ubuntu Forums, IRC have ubuntu+1 rooms for 20.04/development discussions. (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) You could look at changes, ie. https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/focal-changes/2020-February/date.html maybe.  Note:  A change being accepted may not be reflected in the next ISO build but occur the build later (depending on when accepted, and when cron job starts build..)

Comment: AFAICT, Kubuntu 20.04 will ship with Plasma 5.18, not 5.19. Anyway, check out http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/daily-live/pending/focal-desktop-amd64.manifest.

Answer (score 3):

`rmadison` queries the archive database for several different Ubuntu releases including the latest development release which has not been officially released yet. The latest *buntu development release is currently 20.04. The `rmadison` command returns information about package versions, repositories and available architectures. If the same package is provided by more than one repository (e.g. main and focal-proposed) `rmadison` returns package version/architecture information from all the repositories that provide that package.

Run `rmadison` with the following command:

```
rmadison package-name # replace package-name with the name of the package
```

`rmadison` is provided by the *devscripts* package from the default Ubuntu repositories. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install devscripts
```

Comment: That would checking from ubuntu installation about development, but also is there option to find in web way, like from bug#1 OS?

Comment: [Ubuntu Packages Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) has information about all the 20.04 packages in a searchable online database. Ubuntu Packages Search is slower than rmadison because rmadison can fetch information about multiple packages with a single command, but Ubuntu Packages Search can only fetch information about one package at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The .manifest file @ http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/daily-live/current/ lists all the packages and their versions found on the current daily ISO.

FYI Plasma 5.19 is not [released until June 2020](https://community.kde.org/Schedules/Plasma_5), so it will NOT appear in the 
20.04 daily builds.